# combining different statement in where clause

Tags: mysql, where-clause

i have some where clause like:

```
$sWhere = " WHERE MONTH(Inspection_datetime) = '".$Month."' AND 
            YEAR(Inspection_datetime) = '".$Year."' ";
```

and another command:

```
WHERE DAY(Inspection_datetime) BETWEEN 8 AND 14
GROUP BY Line, WEEK(Inspection_datetime), YEAR(Inspection_datetime)
```

how do i do to combine both command become one? because i want to show data in the second week and sort them in selected Month and Year.

Comment: By second week, do you just mean days 8-14 as shown in your question, or do you want to work out the 2nd Mon-Sun week after the first full/partial week?

Comment: @cyberwiki: 8-14 means i want to count or show data in the 2nd week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add another AND clause to your statement.

`" MONTH(Inpsection_datetime) = '".$Month."' AND YEAR(Inspection_datetime) = '".$Year."' AND WHERE DAY(Inspection_datetime) BETWEEN 8 AND 14 GROUP BY Line, WEEK(Inspection_datetime), YEAR(Inspection_datetime)";`

Comment: is this save? could i do like `WHERE .......=MONTH AND .....=YEAR AND DAY(...) BETWEEN 8 AND 14?

Answer (score 0):

WHERE (cond1 AND cond2 AND cond3)
ORDER by (column_to_sort_on) [desc]

I think to sort the query results you have to use "order by ..."

Regards, - M.S.

Answer (score 0):

It is **not** a good idea to perform functions on date columns.  Not unless the table is small or you don't really care about performance, that is.  It is always better to do the reverse - to construct the date &/ range to test against.

> ```
> YEAR(datecolumn) = X and MONTH(datecolumn) = Y
> << index cannot be used, MONTH() has to be run on all rows
> ```

The condition becomes (it looks complicated by works better at MySQL)

```
$sWhere = " WHERE Inspection_datetime >= '".$Year.'-'.$Month."-1'
              AND Inspection_datetime <  '".$Year.'-'.$Month."-1'
                       + interval 1 month - interval 1 day"
```

To add that to the other condition, the whole WHERE clause would be

```
$sWhere = " WHERE Inspection_datetime >= '".$Year.'-'.$Month."1'
              AND Inspection_datetime <  '".$Year.'-'.$Month."1'
                       + interval 1 month - interval 1 day
              AND DAY(Inspection_datetime) BETWEEN 8 AND 14"
```